# Create repeating blocks in word document using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, mailmerge

Hello I am automating a word document from a winforms application using c#. The document contains a number of mail merge fields that I fill from my code. This works fine for fixed fields.

However the document contains a few recurring sections that are repeated n times at run time. Can someone tell me how to create a block of some sort that can be inserted multiple times?

I have tried inserting the text between two bookmarks however this messes up the page formatting.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Edit:

The function below is what I use to merge the data on to the word template. The Dictionary holds the field name in the first string and the content in the second.

The user is given a sample word template with all the field codes in the document and is then able to change the order of the fields and the styling on his own.

```
public static void CreateBody(Application wApp, Document wDoc, Dictionary<string, string> fieldContent)
    {
        //Loop through fields in document body.
        foreach (Field mergeField in wDoc.Fields)
        {
            //Find mailmerge fields in the Word document body.
            if (mergeField.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField)
            {
                //Get the fieldName from the template file.
                string fieldText = mergeField.Code.Text;
                string fieldName = GetFieldName(fieldText);

                if (fieldContent.ContainsKey(fieldName))
                {
                    mergeField.Select();
                    if (fieldContent[fieldName] != "")
                    {
                        wApp.Selection.TypeText(fieldContent[fieldName]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //If the field has no content remove the field text from the word file.
                        wApp.Selection.TypeText(" ");                            
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Now I am looking for a way to repeat a block of mail merge fields in the template and have them be inserted multiple times, once for each record.

Comment: Please show some code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is MSDN link which help you to resolve your issue.

[Building a Word Document Using SQL Server Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192487%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Link-only posts are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Try at least summarizing the relevant information from the page, in case the URL is dead in the future.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the question. I cannot use string writer. The data needs to go to a word-field or similar variable because the end user needs to be able to edit the template file. Both to change formatting and the order of some of the fields.